# xaxis and yaxis is going crazy someone help me

Tags: matplotlib, visualize

I've been struggling to make my xaxis and yaxis look pretty, but I don't know how to make it right....

I've tried to adjust xlim, ylim, xaxis, yaxis...
but those black words of xaixs and yaxis is keep getting overlapped
and this simple thing is driving me crazy!!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(8,1,figsize=(20,10))

i =0
for E in list(type.columns):
    ax[i].plot(type[E])
    i+= 1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDxhF.png)

Comment: One of the problems is that all your data seems to be strings instead of numbers or maybe dates. Another problem is that you created a variable named 'type'.

Comment: OMG you're Genius! Thanks!